# BindingExpression path error property not found in derived class

Tags: c#, xaml

I am confusing with the binding internal property of Base Class.

I am having below classes A , B and I tried to bind the Class "A" property (which is internal) in XAML.

```
  public class A
{
    internal int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    internal static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(A), new PropertyMetadata(0));


}

public class B : A
{

}
```

Question :

While creating the instance for Class A DataContext is set as Class A and can bind the internal property of Class A in XAML for this scenario binding property works without issues

Issue:

But the same scenario I have created an instance of Class B which inherits from Class A, now DataContext is set as Class B and cannot bind the internal property of Class A(from base Class) and error thrown BindingExpression path error property “MyProperty “not found in Class B.

Why scenario not works even its have same base class A ,Please share your ideas about this.

Comment: I think in my own app, I had to make all get/set properties used for binding public, but since you have it as internal and worked I thik that is strange. Maybe you can try to make it public (to isolate the problem).

Comment: Hi Michel, I have tried that one, for property access is public Could not get error "BindingExpression path error property “MyProperty “not found on Class B." But still Could not access the base Class(A) property for an scenario DataContext is set as Class B instance.

Comment: Hello Jeya, in that case hopefully somebody else can provide an answer.

Comment: Even without setting anything to Public, i cannot reproduce your Issue.